# Get code coverage report(junit and instumentation testcases) for eclipse android project

Tags: android, code-coverage, android-instrumentation, clover, eclemma

I have android project which has some Junit test-cases and some instrumentation test-cases.

I am able to generate the code coverage for the Junit test-cases with help of Colver or EclEmma tool.

Now i need to create the code coverage report for Instrumentation test-cases.

Can some one suggest is it possible to generate the code coverage report for android project which is created in eclipse?

Is any tool support code coverage report for instrumentation test-cases?